# How can i run a code thats defined in a different function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I have some code that generate a random value from an array on page load.

```
window.onload = startGame;

    function startGame() {
        document.getElementById("startGame").onclick = startHangman;
        document.getElementById("checkLetter").onclick = checkLetter;
        var hangmanWord = "";
        var words = ["APPLE", "COMPUTER", "BEDSHEET", "CASTE", "WATER", "LANTERN", "COFFE", "PROGRAMMER", "PILLOW", "CHEDDARCHIPOTLE POTETGULL"];
        var hangmanWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
            console.log(hangmanWord);
    }
```

I also have a function that checks if the input value is contained in the random value generated on page load.

```
function checkLetter() {

        var letter = document.getElementById("letter").value.toUpperCase();

        for (var i = 0; i < hangmanWord.length; i++) {
            if (hangmanWord[i] === letter) {
                console.log(hangmanWord[i]);
                var printLetter = document.createElement("p");
                var displayLetter = document.createTextNode(letter);
                printLetter.appendChild(displayLetter);
                document.getElementById("printLetter").appendChild(displayLetter);
            }
        }
```

How can i accomplish this? Do i have to use some sort of function parameter?

Comment: You could make `hangmanWord` a global variable, instead of locally scoped to your `startGame` function.

Comment: Well, why didt i think of that.. Thanks alot. It works :)

Answer (score 0):

Make hangman a global variable, ie change

```
window.onload = startGame;

function startGame() {
    document.getElementById("startGame").onclick = startHangman;
    document.getElementById("checkLetter").onclick = checkLetter;
    var hangmanWord = "";
    var words = ["APPLE", "COMPUTER", "BEDSHEET", "CASTE", "WATER", "LANTERN", "COFFE", "PROGRAMMER", "PILLOW", "CHEDDARCHIPOTLE POTETGULL"];
    var hangmanWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
        console.log(hangmanWord);
}
```

to

```
var hangmanWord = "";
window.onload = startGame;

function startGame() {
    document.getElementById("startGame").onclick = startHangman;
    document.getElementById("checkLetter").onclick = checkLetter;
    var words = ["APPLE", "COMPUTER", "BEDSHEET", "CASTE", "WATER", "LANTERN", "COFFE", "PROGRAMMER", "PILLOW", "CHEDDARCHIPOTLE POTETGULL"];
    hangmanWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
        console.log(hangmanWord); // globa;
}
```

Comment: By doing this, the checkLetter function will only return: " "